# MYSQL - general log file

Tags: mysql

Is here a way to check if there is already a log file where mysql is writing general logs?

I'm trying to start my sql with command: --general-log-file="" to see what kind of queries are being sent to the server but that command is not working.

Answer (score 0):

check for [log_output](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_output)
If the value is NONE log entries are not written even if the logs are enabled. If the logs are not enabled, no logging occurs even if the value of log_output is not NONE.
if it is not None then check for log file name using this [file_name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log_file)

Comment: How/where do I check for these settings?